# Assigning .draggable() and resizable() to dynamicaly created divs

Tags: jquery

yesterday i got answer how to make divs with different id's. But those divs need to be dragable and resizable. I did this with jqueryUI, but i cant find way to implement it in next piece of code (so, to every generated div, it need to bi added .resizable and dragable):

```
var c = 0;
$('#add_txt').on('click', function(){
    $('#vk_main').append('<div id="vk_text_'+ (c++) +'">TEST</div>');
});
```

So, for every div "vk_text_somenumber", must be assigned attributes: .draggable().resizable(); . I tried to do this, but all i got is #vk_main dragable and nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var c = 0;
$('#add_txt').on('click', function(){
    var $div = $('<div id="vk_text_'+ (c++) +'">TEST'+c+'</div>');
    $('#vk_main').append($div);
    $div.draggable();
    $div.resizable();
});​
```

Comment: are you _sure_ that the use of `c++` and `c` in the same expression is not undefined...?

Comment: Ooops, works in Opera, but not in Chrome, i got this error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL". I deleted second C, but it still dont work.

Comment: I found bug, i deleted ; at the end, and now it works in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

you need to attach the the Draggable event to that div, once the page load finishes. so that you can easily drag it.  ( i don know when you are calling click method. but you need to attacg the event in page load)

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
var c = 0;
$('#add_txt').on('click', function(){
    $('#vk_main').append('<div id="vk_text_'+ (c++) +'">TEST</div>');
    $('#vk_text_' + (c++)).draggable(); // (c++) is your random number which is concated with Div
});
}
```

Comment: I tried this too, but for some reason, this dont work. But tnx anyway.